# Set identity: map image of inverse image

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces and $B \subseteq Y$. For a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$, I am going to show that
$$
f[f^{-1}[B]] = f[X] \cap B
$$
$$
y\in f[f^{-1}[B]]\\
\iff \exists a \in f^{-1}[B]: f(a) = y\\
\iff \exists a \in X : f(a) \in B \land f(a) = y\\
\iff \exists a \in X : f(a) = y \land y \in B\\
\iff y\in f[X] \land y \in B\\
\iff y\in f[X] \cap B
$$
Is this correct inference?

Comment: Your argument looks good. $A$ in the statement seems to be irrelevant.